# Neglecting the coefficient time dependence in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose equation
$$
\frac{d^{2}B(t)}{dt^{2}}+f(t)\frac{dB(t)}{dt} + \omega^{2}B(t) = 0
$$
What is the condition of neglecting the time dependence of $f(t)$, i.e., when the solution of this equation isn't significantly different in compare with the case when $f(t) = \text{const}$?